# join with date dimension but don't want NULL for the dates with values

Tags: sql, left-join

I have a query:

```
 SELECT 
    d.FiscalMonth,
    d.FiscalMonthOfYear,
    p.Name
 FROM
     DimDate d
     LEFT JOIN FactSales f on f.SaleDate=d.PKDate
     LEFT JOIN DimPerson p on p.PersonId=f.PersonId
 WHERE d.FiscalYear='2014/7/1'
 group by d.FiscalMonth, d.FiscalMonthOfYear, p.Name
 ORDER BY d.FiscalMonthOfYear asc, p.PersonID asc
```

Which gives me these results:

[image]

Which is all fine, I want to include all months, even the ones that don't have data. (In this case FiscalMonth 2-12.)

The problem I have is with that one NULL value where I have data, IE. FiscalMonthOfYear 1.  The red box.

How would I go about not returning that one "NULL" for the FiscalMonth=2014-07-01?  I've tried some various where clauses but any time I remove the "NULL" values from the results, I also remove all the ones I want (IE. FiscalMonthOfYear 2-12)

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
-Russ

**Update**:

DimDate table has primary key PKDate, which is one row for every date:

```
  DimDate
  PKDate ....
  2014-07-01
  2014-07-02
  2014-07-03
  etc.
```

FaceSales table has one ore many Sales transactions for a given day:

```
  FactSales
  SaleDate       Amount
  2014-07-01     34.99
  2014-07-01     21.89
  2014-07-02     24.77
  2014-07-04     22.77
```

The problem is that FactSales may not have a sale on a particular day.  So my query is finding that one (or many) days with no transactions, and because of the LEFT JOIN is returning it.  How would I go about removing this result so it's not in my results?

```
  SELECT
       d.PKDate
       ,f.SaleDate

 FROM
     DimDate d
     LEFT JOIN FactSales f on f.SaleDate=d.PKDate
     LEFT JOIN DimPerson p on p.PersonId=f.PersonId
 WHERE d.FiscalYear='2014/7/1'
 ORDER BY d.PKDate
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with your tables and some sample data?

Comment: p.PersonID needs to be in the GROUP BY for that query to run, but other than that it looks reasonable. Hard to tell without seeing the data.

Comment: @bluefeet: I'm not as familiar with sql fiddle as I should be.  I'll play with it, and see if I can get a working example.

Comment: @CheeseInPosition I've updated with some additional info.  The problem is the FactSales may not have a row for a particular date, but the LEFT JOIN from DimDate is finding all dates, so returning that NULL record.  Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems stems from the fact that you are actually trying to do two things at once:

- You want all the Names related to sales of fiscal months with at
  least one sale
- You want an extra row for all fiscal month with no
  sales

As often goes in these cases... you should solve the two distinct problems and then put together the results (with a UNION in this specific case).

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    d.FiscalMonth,
    d.FiscalMonthOfYear,
    p.Name
  FROM DimDate   d
  JOIN FactSales f ON f.SaleDate=d.PKDate
  JOIN DimPerson p ON p.PersonId=f.PersonId
  WHERE d.FiscalYear='2014/7/1'
) UNION (
  SELECT
    d.FiscalMonth,
    d.FiscalMonthOfYear,
    NULL AS Name
  FROM      DimDate   d
  LEFT JOIN FactSales f ON f.SaleDate=d.PKDate
  WHERE d.FiscalYear='2014/7/1'
  GROUP BY d.FiscalMonth, d.FiscalMonthOfYear, p.Name
  HAVING COUNT(f.SaleDate)=0
)
ORDER BY FiscalMonthOfYear asc, PersonID ASC
```

I haven't tested it, and there may be some better ways to solve the second part (SUBSELECT, EXISTS) but that depends a bit on the engine you are using.

Comment: This did the trick.  I felt I was trying to do two contradictory things, but couldn't put my finger on it.  Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join as follows:

```
SELECT 
    d.FiscalMonth,
    d.FiscalMonthOfYear,
    p.Name
 FROM
     DimDate d
     INNER JOIN FactSales f on f.SaleDate=d.PKDate
     LEFT JOIN DimPerson p on p.PersonId=f.PersonId
 WHERE d.FiscalYear='2014/7/1'
 group by d.FiscalMonth, d.FiscalMonthOfYear, p.Name
 ORDER BY d.FiscalMonthOfYear asc, p.PersonID asc
```

The inner join does a union of the two tables without giving priority to the left table. For more on joins you can read this blog: [Visual representation of sql joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)
Which states that an `INNER JOIN` **will return all of the records in the left table (table A) that have a matching record in the right table (table B)** whearas a `LEFT JOIN` **will return all of the records in the left table (table A) regardless if any of those records have a match in the right table (table B)**

Comment: Actually it's a LEFT join that I want though.  I basically want all the records (grouped by month) in the DimDate table regardless of whether they have a matching record in the FactSales table.  My goal is a list of each months totals, if no totals, then NULL so each month is listed, like http://i.stack.imgur.com/Npk6q.png minus the red box.